# PHP: How to catch an exception from a method within another class?

Tags: php, mysql, database, exception, try-catch

I'm using a class for database connection, this class holds the CRUD methods, and also the database connection methods.

It's basically the core of all other classes that uses the DB.

I'm currently facing a problem on dealing with duplicate entry in unique columns, when inserting a record.

**Database.class.php** insertDB method:

```
class Database {
(...)       
public function insertDB($sql,$params=null){
            $con=$this->connect();
            $query=$con->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute($params);
            $rs = $con->lastInsertId();
            return $rs;
            self::__destruct();
        }
(...)
}
```

There is another class, PersonDAO.class.php, which is a class that inherits Database.class.

PersonDAO.class.php has its own method for inserting a record, which finally uses Database.class.php InsertBD method.

**PersonDAO.class.php** insert method: (notice it **calls insertDB** at the end).

```
class PersonDAO extends Database{
(...)
    public function insert ($fields, $params=null) {
        $numparams="";
        for($i=0;$i<count($params);$i++) $numparams .= ",?";
        $numparams=substr($numparams, 1);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Person ($fields) VALUES ($numparams)";
        $t=$this->insertDB($sql,$params);
        return $t;
    } 
(...)
}
```

The problem occurs in the registration form **register.php**, when I instantiate PersonDAO and use its insert method for inserting a duplicate entry into a column set as unique.

```
(...)
       $person= new PersonDAO();
       $fields="email,name";
       $email="john@doe.com"; //already existing record. email column set as unique
       $name="John Doe";
       $params=array($email,$name);
       try {
             $rs = $person->insert($fields,$params);
       } catch (PDOException $e) {
             if ($e->errorInfo[1] == 1062) {
                echo "Cannot insert record. Duplicate entry";
             } 
       } 
(...)
```

It's not catching duplicate entry exception, as if there was no errors.

var_dump($rs) contains:

```
string(1) "0"
```

But should not it catch PDOException and print "Cannot insert record. Duplicate entry"?

Comment: I can only imagine what is happening is that error reporting is turned off and PDO is not set to throw exceptions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992795/set-pdo-to-throw-exceptions-by-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any "Uncaught Exception ..." message ? Perhaps, You first need to catch the Exception in your **Database.class.php** insertDB method and then throw it.

```
class Database {
(...)       
public function insertDB($sql,$params=null){
        try{
            $con=$this->connect();
            $query=$con->prepare($sql);
            $query->execute($params);
            $rs = $con->lastInsertId();
            return $rs;
            self::__destruct();
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            throw $e;
        }
    }
(...)
}
```

Or if there is no error at all. Check

```
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```