# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to get the last value of `numAlarms` and Update it if exist and insert it if it's not exist

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

if (isset($_GET['stdId'])) {
    $stdId = $_GET['stdId'];
}

if (isset($_GET['subR'])) {
    $subR = $_GET['subR'];
}

        $getInc = $db->prepare("SELECT numAlarms FROM stud_abs_alerts WHERE studId=? AND sub_id=?");
        $getInc->bind_param('ii', $stdId, $subR);
        if ($getInc->execute()) {
            $rest = $getInc->get_result();
            if ($a = mysqli_fetch_array($rest)) {
                $inc = $a['numAlarms'];
                $increment = ++$a;
                $id = "";
                $numAlarms = 1;

                //var_dump($rest);

                $getInfo = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO stud_abs_alerts (id, studId, sub_id, numAlarms) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE numAlarms=VALUES(?)');
                $getInfo->bind_param('iiiii', $id, $stdId, $subR, $numAlarms, $numAlarms);

                if ($getInfo->execute()) {
                    echo "done";
                } else {
                    echo "Error";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

GOT : `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object`

Comment: Try var_dump($getInfo); it seems to be failing during the prepare, and will therefore return false instead of an object. If you turn on PDO exceptions it should give you a useful error message. Also I think you are missing a variable in your bind_param, you need to add another $numAlarms

Comment: @rjdown thanks yes I was missing `$numAlarms` now it did put it but still the same

Comment: Well, turn on PDO exceptions and see what is causing prepare to return false. See here for how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992795/set-pdo-to-throw-exceptions-by-default

Comment: @rjdown Thanks in fact I am using mySqli so I am looking now at this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: Oops my bad, yep that'll work

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

> Return Values  mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or **FALSE if
>   an error occurred**.

Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object means that $getInfo, is not an object. So an error must have occurred and a boolean is returned instead of an object.

**EDIT:**

You have some error here:

> $getInc = $db->prepare("SELECT numAlarms FROM stud_abs_alerts WHERE studId=? AND sub_id=?");

Probably some invalid field. Try this:

```
$getInc = $db->prepare("SELECT numAlarms FROM stud_abs_alerts WHERE studId=? AND sub_id=?");
if($getInc == false) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
$getInc->bind_param('ii', $stdId, $subR);
```

And see the error.

Comment: Thanks I got it but where is the problem then