# Unexpected results in PDO Transactions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My problem is kinda simple or it maybe a silly mistake from my side. But I don't know I am just getting unexpected results while using PDO in php.

Code goes like this,

```
try
{
    $_pdo = get_pdo_instance();

    $_pdo->beginTransaction();

    //query 1
    $_pdo->query("some query"); // I have error in query 3 but this query 1 is still executed.

    //query 2
    $_pdo->query("some query"); // only executes when there are no errors.

    //query 3
    $_pdo->query("some wrong query"); // let's say I have an error in this sql

    $_pdo->commit();

}
catch(Exception $ex)
{
    $_pdo->rollback();
}
```

I am explaining the problem now, 
In given example I have some sql error in `query 3`, so none the queries should run as they all belongs to single transaction.

But in my case `query 1` always run even if there are errors in that `try` block.

Maybe its something simple but I have no idea why this is happening.

Edit:
Function definition,

```
function get_pdo_instance()
{
    try 
    {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        die('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $conn;
}
```

Comment: Where are you creating `$_pdo`? Is it outside the `try`?

Comment: I think you are missing this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8992933/1169798 You have to tell PDO to throw Exceptions upon failed queries. Otherwise it will just return `false` from the query and proceed.

Comment: @Jordy I have `get_pdo_instance()` function defined somewhere in my file. This functions creates and return the pdo connection.

Comment: @Sirko I will give that a try, but why only query 1 is executed but not query 2 ?

Comment: Does your query have a database definition language (DDL) statement? Statements such as `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` get committed automatically, even if you later rollback.

Comment: @che-azeh Just Insert and Update queries. Nothing else.

Comment: Just for completeness sake: have you checked the return value of `beginTransaction()`?

Comment: @Sirko It returns Bool(true).

Comment: What MySQL storage engine are you using for your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are used only for PHP errors. In the code above, you're trying to catch a MySQL error. When PHP reads your try block, everything looks fine, and it therefore has no exception to catch.
You can do error checking with PDO and MySQL like:

```
if(!$_pdo->query("some query")) {
// Do something
}
```

Comment: One can set PDO to actually throw exceptions - see the other answer. But your solution would be valid as well.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [PDO Error Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php).  You need to turn exception raising on.

```
try {
  $_pdo = get_pdo_instance();
  $_pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $_pdo->beginTransaction();
  $_pdo->query("some query");
  $_pdo->query("some query");
  $_pdo->query("some wrong query");
  $_pdo->commit();
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
  $_pdo->rollback();
}
```

Comment: It is ON, check my function code in my post. Or do you think I have to do it outside the function ? If so, what's the reason ?

Comment: Ah ok. I missed that. You shouldn't have to do it outside the function definition. Are you sure the that the SQL statements are invalid and code execution is going into the catch block? If the SQL is valid then no exception will be raised. Also, can you clarify... are you expecting a PDOException to be raised when 0 results are returned?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution,

I was catching `Exception`, instead in this case I had to do catch `PDOException`.

I guess that solved my problem, but I haven't tested this thing completely. I will post updates if any.

Comment: Catching `\Exception` would catch `PDOException`.

Comment: @N.B. I am personally not sure about this, so I didn't selected my answer as correct. Still checking things.